# Kubuntu sddm rotated login screen (20.04)

Tags: kubuntu, 20.04, login-screen, display-rotation

The login screen has the wrong rotation(portrait). After I log in the rotation is like it should be (landscape).

Where/how do I change the screen rotation of the login screen for kubuntu sddm?

I am using ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I answered my own question just to make it easier for other people to find a solution for the problem. I create this because I couldn't find another thread that had a straight forward solution for the kubuntu sddm screen rotation issue.

Answer (score 4):

- Add `xrandr --output screen --rotate rotation` to `/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup` file where:

  - screen = eDP-1/DP-1 or else (run `xrandr` command to find your screen name)
  - rotation = left/right/normal/inverted
- In `/etc/sddm.conf.d`, create a file ended with .conf (e.g. login-screen.conf). Add following lines to the config file:

```
[X11]
DisplayCommand=/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup
```

Comment: What if there is/will be no `xrandr` on the system? Pure Wayland as example.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file at /usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup and add
`xrandr -o left` **or** `xrandr -o right`, depending on how your screen is oriented.

Now open the file at `/var/lib/sddm/state.conf` and add these lines:

```
[X11]
DisplayCommand=/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup
```

Log out and enjoy your now correctly rotated login screen.

Comment: This is the closest I've been to an answer. Thanks for your effort. It appears you pasted the command to add to the second file rather than the file itself. To what file do I add DisplayCommand=/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Building on top of @DevShot's response

This is the same:

Open the file at `/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup` and add one of these lines depending on how your screen is rotated:

```
xrandr -o left

or

xrandr -o right
```

Then add the lines below to the end of `/var/lib/sddm/state.conf` :

```
[X11]
DisplayCommand=/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, Especially for the ```/var/lib/sddm/state.conf``` path. I noticed just now that this was completely missing from my original answer. I've added this to my old response as well to not mislead any potential readers of the original post.