# Kubuntu 20.04/21.04 initial login screen display resolution

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

experiencing and odd issue with the resolution displayed on my system when I initially boot into Kubuntu - it's occurring with both 20.04 AND 21.04.  On initial boot prior to login, I get a mirror of the laptop screen on the secondary monitor that covers the secondary monitor partially - it results in it looking like this: https://photos.app.goo.gl/ZxojAMDv3BvSG83D8

From what I've been able to discern, this laptop uses an AMD Ryzen Graphics chip for the laptop and an nVidia 2060M for the external display port.  nVidia is using the .  xrandr configuration is as follows:

DP-2 connected primary 3840x1600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 879mm x 366mm
eDP-1-0 connected 1920x1080+3975+857 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm

Once I login, the desktop works as expected and the lock screen respects the monitor configuration if I lock it post-login.    I've looked for a conf file for SDDM that I can use to modify the screen resolutions and layout to match what xrandr sees, but no success.  Tried autorandr and a fresh install of 21.04 with no change.

I also tried the solution provided here: [Kubuntu sddm rotated login screen (20.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254937/kubuntu-sddm-rotated-login-screen-20-04)

I added the text to a new .conf file named login-screen.conf inside /etc/sddm.conf.d/ and added the following text:

```
    [X11]
DisplayCommand=/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup
```

and in the Xsetup file I placed the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Xsetup - run as root before the login dialog appears

xrandr --output DP-1 --off
xrandr --output DP-2 --mode 3840x1600 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output eDP-1-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 3975x857 --rotate normal

if [ -e /sbin/prime-offload ]; then
    echo running NVIDIA Prime setup /sbin/prime-offload
    /sbin/prime-offload
fi
```

Unfortunately, a reboot exhibited the same behavior.
Steps I've already taken:

1. Display Setup in System synced
2. NVidia driver update - currently 460 but 465 exhibited same behavior under 20.04
3. https://blog.victormendonca.com/2018/06/29/how-to-fix-sddm-on-multiple-screens/

I'm wondering if I've missed something or if perhaps I'm adding the configuraton to the wrong configuration file.  If that's the case, I'd appreciate a pointer as I'm still relatively new.

TIA,

Mike

Comment: Assuming you're talking about a *deb* based release, your KDE settings aren't used until after you've logged in - ie. any KDE/Qt settings are not used by `sddm` until after you've entered your login & the greeter has finished it's role & KDE or your desktop starts.  `sddm` has its own settings it uses; if you don't like `sddm` it can be swapped out; but the same will apply to other DMs too for the most part, but `sddm` was not designed for use with Ubuntu Core 20 & like *snap* only releases.

Comment: You're correct that I was referring to a deb based release.  It's not a question of liking or disliking sddm - I'm just trying to figure out how to get the resolution set in such a way as to prevent the overlap.  Am I incorrect in presuming that there should be a way that I could address the login screen issue?

Comment: The lock screen you mention occurs whilst KDE is operating, it's not `sddm` thus why no issues there. I've seen your issue before (thinking of your provided photo), but sorry I can't recall where (if a support issue, bug report on launchpad, or where I saw it). I suspect it wasn't me but a support/bug report..  yes your presumption would be valid, unless it's a reported issue (https://github.com/sddm/sddm/issues) and remains open because of a specific issue that maybe related to video drivers (eg. nvidia only); https://github.com/sddm/sddm/issues/1424 looks close to yours for eg...

Comment: @guiverc  the link you provided to the bug report is the issue exactly....I don't know whether it's helpful to know I'm not the only one, but now I don't feel bad that I wasn't able to find a solution.  Thank you for taking the time to help!

Comment: I'd recommend adding a comment that says it affects you too ('affects me too' being the tag in launchpad), as bugs hitting multiple users on different platforms (kde neon & kubuntu is almost the same, not quite) adds weight to report.. That wasn't the report I was referring to when I said I've seen it before, but yeah i looked close thus why I added it (ps: I note you may have already done what I'm suggesting, if so, Thank you for making Kubuntu, sddm & open source better by taking the time to file reports!)

Comment: sorry, I'm a bit of a Git noob - I'm not seeing a method by which I can add a comment to the bugreport

Comment: You'll need to be signed in (have an account with github) and leave a comment like *toreric* did.. ie. some details about your system, OS release etc and how it impacts you (link to photo is also worthwhile).   Best if you include details of `sddm` specifically; ie. I'd use `apt-cache policy sddm` to view package details; my own is `0.19.0-2ubuntu2`, and I'd use 21.04 for reporting (not 20.04) as *devs* care about current versions a lot more than older versions of their software.  In fact look at https://github.com/sddm/sddm which may have some clues on setting DPI

Comment: I have a github account and have left a comment, although I'll update it with the info from the `apt-cache policy sddm` - my post is just above toreric's (Spectre-63) - apologies for the confusion.  I thought there was an additional labeling process you were referring to that was helpful/necessary

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to look at the sddm docs - I got hopeful when I saw the custom DPI, but unfortunately it suggests setting a Custom DPI by adding an argument to /etc/sddm.conf - the file doesn't exist.  I also tried to follow the suggestion to modify the xorg.conf but, similarly, that file doesn't exist in the location referenced in the docs (/etc/X11)

Comment: Note: I'll be talking about Lubuntu here as it's what I'm involved with; we use `sddm` too, Lubuntu using the same Qt5 in LXQt as used by KDE. A default Lubuntu install doesn't create `/etc/sddm.conf` file (what I saw and made up my last comment; my primary box running *impish* - I'll delete that comment now), but the file IS created and used if certain options are during install.  An non-existent file is not unexpected in Lubuntu and quite possibly Kubuntu (*I tried to find a Kubuntu QA-test install i did Tue-29-June to confirm, but I either used a different box or it's been wiped already*).